# Add custom method for slice string[]

Tags: go

I'm creating a utility package for my project.

Many of my string slices need a function to 
1. remove duplicates
2. remove empty strings

I know 1 way to do this:1. Add a function for each case which accepts a string slice and returns a string slice

```
func removeEmpty(s []string) []string {

    i := 0 // i points to next available pos

    for _, v := range s {
        if v != "" {
            s[i] = v
            i++
        }
    }

    return s[:i]
}

func dedup(s []string) []string {

    i := 0 // i points to next available pos
    mp := map[string]bool{}

    for _, v := range s {
        if _, ok := mp[v]; !ok {
            s[i] = v
            mp[v] = true
            i++
        }
    }

    return s[:i]
}
```

when I apply these 2 functions to my slice, I can do:

```
mySlice := string[]{}
mySlice = dedup(removeEmpty(mySlice))
```

I want to make it somthing like:

```
mySlice = mySlice.dedup().removeEmpty()
```

or

```
mySlice.dedup().removeEmpty()
```

Maybe I can add custom method to slice[] ?

I tried writing it

```
func (s []string) removeEmpty() {

}
```

I'm getting complie error.

Comment: This is not particularly idiomatic Go, and will likely throw off other developers working on the project. The normal way to do this would be what you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define methods on `[]string`, but you can define your own type based on `[]string` and define methods on that:

```
type myStringSlice []string

func (s myStringSlice) removeEmpty() myStringSlice {
    i := 0 // i points to next available pos

    for _, v := range s {
        if v != "" {
            s[i] = v
            i++
        }
    }

    return s[:i]
}

func (s myStringSlice) dedup() myStringSlice {

    i := 0 // i points to next available pos
    mp := map[string]bool{}

    for _, v := range s {
        if _, ok := mp[v]; !ok {
            s[i] = v
            mp[v] = true
            i++
        }
    }

    return s[:i]
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/u1z_N3c_wPP.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation:

> You can only declare a method with a receiver whose type is defined in the same package as the method. You cannot declare a method with a receiver whose type is defined in another package.

So you have to declare a type on `[]string` and then declare the method on your own type.